# How do I calculate YTD pay in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet like this to track the salary and amount paid each month to my employees.

[image]

I run a small company but as it got bigger I decided to give pay stubs to each employee.

[image]

How do I make it so when I input a Emp ID# the Year-to-date pay pops up?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the list of paid salaries is in `Salaries!A2:D`, use this:

`=sumif(Salaries!A$2:A, A2, Salaries!D$2:D)`